# Closedxml - get the link to an already open Excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I have a project VSTO EXCEL. I would like to work with ClosedXML library, but can`t get the link on the open ActiveSheet. My code:

```
private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var workbook = **?**;
        var ws = workbook.Worksheet(1);
        var rngHeaders = ws.Range("B3:F3");
        rngHeaders.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.LightSalmon;
    }
```

This example does`t work:

```
var workbook = ThisApplication.ThisWorkbook;
```

I know there is this way:

```
    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
{
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
    worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
    workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
}
```

But I have to work with already opened Workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open an Excel file with ClosedXML, you have to open a saved file (by filename) or a filestream. You can't open a workbook which is already opened in Excel or another application.